# Download bytes docx api rest

Tags: java, spring, pdf

O código mostra um método que é chamado pelo navegador para gerar um PDF. Os bytes foram gerados pelo Jasper. O código funciona normalmente.

```
@GetMapping("/relatorios/teste")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> relatorio() throws Exception{
    byte[] relatorio = lancamentoService.relatorio();

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
        .body(relatorio);
}
```

OBS1: Meu problema é quando tenho os bytes de um docx! Já tentei fazer algo similar ao PDF, mas ainda não obtive êxito, tentei diversos códigos encontrados pela net e nada.

OBS2: Os bytes docx eu gero usando o Apache POI.

Comment: Está usando Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro algumas alterações no seu esquema de download, a segunda não é obrigatória mas eu recomendo mesmo assim:

1. Utilize `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` já que você trabalha com vários formatos, esse tipo é considerado um dado arbitrário segundo a [RFC2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#page-13) e vai servir nesse caso.
2. Adicionar no header a propriedade para evitar cache `no-cache` (não obrigatório)

E por fim atualizar seu código para construir o `ResponseEntity` desta forma:

```
@GetMapping("/relatorios/teste")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> relatorio() throws Exception {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(lancamentoService.relatorio(), getConfiguredAttachmentHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
}

private HttpHeaders getConfiguredAttachmentHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache().getHeaderValue());
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    return httpHeaders;
}
```